# How to make a eclipse plug-in more attractive?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

i have made an eclipse Plug-in. but i am not happy with its UI. Can we make it more attractive by changing its color, themes or can we using something like animation etc in this? Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Oh, please no! Make it attractive by providing a consistent, usable UI that blends in with the rest while providing all the necessary tools to get my job done. Don't "prettify" it with colors, themes or animations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the comments say it best, dont think that adding animations or colors makes your plugin more attractive. Fokus on usability.

- Adding things like tree or table structures to organize information makes a big difference.
- Look at the different variations of tables and trees, some add functionality such as filtering or virtual tables that fill in realtime.
- Use icons with proper hover texts where appropriate.
- Enable/disable actions/icons when you can.

Alot of these small things make a big difference in how "pretty" the plugin appears.

Keep in mind that the plugin you make can be used in different operating systems, so it has to blend in both in Windows and Unix.

There is a guide for user interfaces in Eclipse [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines) with many guidelines.

Comment: thanks a lot Fredrik. I have done with many of the functionality you discussed here...