# How to check Eclipse plugin performance

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development.

I have been modifying a plugin that was used in our team, and i don't want to add new bottle-necks.

Also the eclipse to which i am integrating to is taking too much time to install the plugin. any suggestion on how to identify the reason for that?

So i would like to know some tips on

- How to check performance of a plugin - any tools that are available. (like jprofiler in java or any other performance analyser tool)
- How to check for bottleneck in my plugin code using some tools.

And is there a doc that tell the do's and don't of the plugin development.

Comment: Aren't installing time and plugin performance two completely different things? If your plugin takes too much time to install then I think it is because of osgi and p2 of the host where the plugin is being installed to is taking too much time.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker my mistake, i wanted to put both issues into context. and somehow mistakenly related the issues. anyway updated the question

Comment: I've found the fastest way to install an Eclipse plugin is to turn off "Contact all update sites" option in the UI. This requires that all your plugin's dependencies can be resolved from your update site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining performance of a plugin isnt that much different from any ordinary java program. It works in similar ways. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580091/207764) for example.

It takes long to install; It seem like that would be an issue of the underlaying program, P2, rather than your plugin. At installation of a plugin your manifest is read, some information about your extensions are saved in Eclipse. The actual plugin is copied. Dependencies checked. It seems like these things shouldn't take that long, unless you have a very large plugin?
Perhaps you are installing the plugin into an environment that already have alot of plugin? Try downloading a clean Eclipse, do you have the same issue there?

Make sure you don't set your plugin to start automatically when the user starts Eclipse. That is bad behaviour that causes clutter and general slowdown for the users. The plugin should be started when the user actually wants to use it, not a second before.

Also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12139224/207764) might help with the general design of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, measure everything, as you should never try to optimize just by guessing performance bottlenecks. I recommend [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) for all Java code (Eclipse plugins as well as plain Java code).

The second important thing: If you have functionality that takes more time than the twinkling of an eye, make it a [job in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html), so it can run in the background. It is fine for something to run some seconds, if it does not stop the user from working.