# Eclipse plugins aweful slow, but which one? A way of measuring plugin performance?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Hello @stackoverflow'ers,

I am using eclipse since years and I like the IDE, but in the past the eclipse is slowing me extremely down. I have no clue if it is a eclipse, a plugin or even a OS issue.

I only feel the performance impact.
For example:

- I have provided the Eclipse 1,25GB Heap, anyway my eclipse eats up the heap over the day.
- On content assist it happens sometimes, that eclipse is freezing for 5-10 seconds
- On typing (I assume also the content assist) is sometime also freezing and waiting for multiple seconds
- sometime eclipse is freezing at all, so nothing happens with the IDE.

I am working under Ubuntu 14.04, but colleagues on Windows have the same issue. So, probably it is not dependent on OS, but I am not fully sure.

The question to me is now:

- is there a way to trace plugins regarding the performance impacting the developer?
- is there a way to trace the performance of specific plugins? (jvisualvm seems not to be sufficient)
- is there a way to trace all plugins and execution of plugins involved on content assist?
- is there a way to temporarily disable plugins on runtime of eclipse to dig down to the responsible plugin?

Hopefully someone can help me out of the dark

Comment: Have you checked already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373866/how-to-check-eclipse-plugin-performance ?
Maybe it helps?

Comment: hkais, it helps a bit, but does not solve the issue. Right now I am still searching for a way to see how plugins stop or interrupt users interactions. E.g. if you have a plugin which eats all resources of your eclipse during development. So I hope there is a solution in eclipse already to intercept alls api calls from plugins

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window--> Preferences -->Startup and Shutdown

De select the unwanted features. This will reduce the number of plugins getting activated during the start up time. It took too much time for me for eclipse to start up and after doing this it started in few seconds and performance is also good. Give a try.

Comment: Santhosh, I have time on startup so saving mutiple seconds on startup is not my issue. My issue is during working with eclipse.